# How can I connect with X509 by putting all options in the connection string in node.js driver for mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, connection-string, x509, adonis.js

I'm using the keys available in [mongodb docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/MongoClient.html)
for a self-signed certificate using X509 authentication with a Node.js Driver.

When trying to connect to the database I get the following error:

`MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [pedro.com:57040] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: unable to verify the first certificate]`

Despite that error, I am sure that the connection works as I am using Studio 3T and everything is up and running by using the same certificates.

So my question is... how can I programmatically connect to a database using x509 certificate by writing all the options in the connection string? Perhaps the keys that I am giving are wrong? Or some are missing?

```
db: `mongodb://CN=pedro.com,OU=IT,O=Polygon,L=Setubal,ST=Setubal,C=PT@pedro.com:57040,pedro.com:57041
,pedro.com:57042/testBO?
ssl=true&authMechanism=MONGODB-X509
&sslPEMKeyFile=${fs.readFileSync(
        `${Helpers.appRoot(Env.get('DB_SSL_CERT'))}`
      )}
&sslCAFile=${fs.readFileSync(
        `${Helpers.appRoot(Env.get('DB_SSL_CA'))}`
      )}&replicaSet=testReplica`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure both server and client can verify each other's certificates. The two verifications are independent and use different options.

For server side see https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/blob/master/.evergreen/run-tests.sh#L74, for client side see https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/blob/master/.evergreen/run-tests.sh#L91. URI options are standardized across drivers.

Also see https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/blob/master/spec/README.md#x509-authentication.

`sslPEMKeyFile` is a legacy node driver option (assuming it is valid), the tls* options take paths to files and not file contents.

Comment: thank you a lot. By switching everything to tls and a few other small fixes made it work :)

Comment: can u post your solution, with regards to "small fixes"