# spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive setting keystore password from application.yml for connecting using X509

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mongodb

In order to connect to mongodb using reactive streams by authenticating as X509 user, mongo db driver forces to set two jvm properties:
`javax.net.ssl.keyStore`
`javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword`
https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.0/driver-reactive/tutorials/ssl/

I have only been able to set the properties and make it work **before** application start

```java
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "path");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");
SpringApplication.run(ChgQuerySvcApplication.class, args);
```

However if I try to set those properties in a class that extends `AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration`
It doesn't pick up.

```java
@Configuration
public class ReactiveMongoConfiguration extends AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    @Value("${mypassword}")
    private String keyStorePassword;

    @Override
    public MongoClient reactiveMongoClient() {

        MongoProperties properties = new MongoProperties();
        properties.setDatabase("somdedb");
        String uri = "mongodb+srv://CN=username@clusteraddress/somedb?authSource=%24external&authMechanism=MONGODB-X509&retryWrites=true&w=majority";
        properties.setUri(uri);
        ReactiveMongoClientFactory factory = new ReactiveMongoClientFactory(properties, environment, null);

        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "path to key store");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password"); // possibly replace with keyStorePassword
        MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createMongoX509Credential("CN=username"); // redundant, I know
        MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyToSslSettings(builder -> builder
                        .applySettings(SslSettings.builder().enabled(true).invalidHostNameAllowed(true).build()))
                .credential(credential).build();
        return factory.createMongoClient(settings);

    }
}
```

The spring starter dependency(version 2.3.2.RELEASE) I am using:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

When I try to connect, I get the following exception:

```
{"@timestamp":"2020-08-07T17:34:18.346-05:00","logger_name":"org.mongodb.driver.client","thread_name":"async-channel-group-0-handler-executor","severity":"ERROR","trace":"","span":"","parent":"","message":"Calling onError threw an exception","stack_trace":"com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18 (AuthenticationFailed): 'No verified subject name available from client' on server servername:27017. The full response is {\"operationTime\": {\"$timestamp\": {\"t\": 1596839653, \"i\": 1}}, \"ok\": 0.0, \"errmsg\": \"No verified subject name available from client\", \"code\": 18, \"codeName\": \"AuthenticationFailed\", \"$clusterTime\": {\"clusterTime\": {\"$timestamp\": {\"t\": 1596839653, \"i\": 1}}, \"signature\": {\"hash\": {\"$binary\": {\"base64\": \"4IS/JaRasdauyWO9aXVOcaHm2s+3KzKg=\", \"subType\": \"00\"}}, \"keyId\": 123234}}}\r\n\tat com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:175)\r\n\tat com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$2$1.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:389)\r\n\t... 13 common frames omitted\r\nWrapped by: com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating\r\n\tat com.mongodb.internal.connection.X509Authenticator.translat...\r\n"}
{"@timestamp":"2020-08-07T17:34:18.347-05:00","logger_name":"org.mongodb.driver.client","thread_name":"async-channel-group-0-handler-executor","severity":"ERROR","trace":"","span":"","parent":"","message":"Callback onResult call produced an error","stack_trace":"com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18 (AuthenticationFailed): 'No verified subject name available from client' on server servername:27017. The full response is {\"operationTime\": {\"$timestamp\": {\"t\": 1596839653, \"i\": 1}}, \"ok\": 0.0, \"errmsg\": \"No verified subject name available from client\", \"code\": 18, \"codeName\": \"AuthenticationFailed\", \"$clusterTime\": {\"clusterTime\": {\"$timestamp\": {\"t\": 1596839653, \"i\": 1}}, \"signature\": {\"hash\": {\"$binary\": {\"base64\": \"4IS/asdJaRuyaWO9XVOcaHm2s+3KzKg=\", \"subType\": \"00\"}}, \"keyId\": 123234}}}\r\n\tat com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:175)\r\n\tat com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$2$1.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:389)\r\n\t... 13 common frames omitted\r\nWrapped by: com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating\r\n\tat com.mongodb.internal.connection.X509Authenticator.translat...\r\n"}
```

The reason I am trying to do that is so that I can set the password through spring cloud config instead of hardcoding or passing as JVM Argument. Is there a way to set those properties dynamically ?

Comment: All x509 options can be provided via the connection string. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63188502/how-can-i-connect-with-x509-by-putting-all-options-in-the-connection-string-in-n/63194197#63194197

Comment: I see that the link you provided was for a node.js driver and sub comments had a link to ruby driver, do you know if that is true for the Java driver too ? I tried this,
`&tls=true&tlsCertificateKeyFile=X509-readwrite.pem`
still failed, also to put it out there, this is a connection to MongoDB Atlas.

Comment: I was referencing the documentation here: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.1/driver-reactive/tutorials/ssl/

Comment: Verify you can connect using mongo shell using your URI, if the same connection string is not working using a driver this is likely a bug.

Comment: I am able to connect throw mongo shell using `mongo "mongodb+srv://atlas-cluster-name/dbname?authSource=%24external&authMechanism=MONGODB-X509" --tls --tlsCertificateKeyFile .\X509-file.pem` 

However, when I try:


`String uri = "mongodb://CN=user@atlas-cluster-name/dbname?&authSource=%24external&authMechanism=MONGODB-X509&retryWrites=true&w=majority&tls=true&tlsCertificateKeyFile=X509-file.pem";`


It still gives authentication failed

Comment: Has anyone done that through a java driver ? without using the JWM arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr**

We were able to provide a new SSLContext to MongoDB connection factory using springboot's [MongoClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer.html) before creating a MongoDB Connection, essentially overwriting the default `SSLContext` Available in JVM

**Detailed Explanation:**

MongoDB's Java driver relies solely on the `SSLContext` in JRE and thus there is no way to
set it through connection string etc. I confirmed this with MongoDB Support. Since we leverage `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive`. We were able to use some of the Customizers provided by spring-boot. Here is how we solved it:

We created a bean of the customizer:

```java
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MongoX509CredentialClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer implements MongoClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer {

    private static final String MONGO_KEY_ENTRY_ALIAS = "mongo-client-key";

    private static final JcaX509CertificateConverter X509_CERTIFICATE_CONVERTER = new JcaX509CertificateConverter();

    private static final JcaPEMKeyConverter PEM_KEY_CONVERTER = new JcaPEMKeyConverter();

    private final MongoX509Properties properties;

    /**
     * Only customizes the {@link SslSettings} for use with X.509 Certificate
     * Authentication
     */
    @Override
    public void customize(Builder clientSettingsBuilder) {
        // @formatter:off
        clientSettingsBuilder
            .applyToSslSettings(builder -> builder
                    .applySettings(SslSettings
                            .builder()
                            .context(sslContext())
                            .enabled(true)
                            .build()))
            .credential(MongoCredential.createMongoX509Credential());
        // @formatter:on
    }

    /**
     * Creates an {@link SSLContext} that can connect to any endpoint exposing a
     * valid well known CA by the JRE. And uses a dynamic array of
     * {@link KeyManager} that contains the {@link X509Certificate} and
     * {@link PrivateKey} configured for use with a MongoDB instance.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @SneakyThrows
    public SSLContext sslContext() {
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance(properties.getTlsVersion());
        sslContext.init(keyManagers(x509Certificate(), privateKey()), trustManagers(), null);
        return sslContext;
    }

    /**
     * Creates an array of {@link TrustManager} containing the default set of
     * trusted certificate authorities. This is required to make a TLS connection to
     * the MongoDB instance. If MongoDB is Atlas then the CA is Let's Encrypt and
     * should already be trusted so copy that over to the SSLContext that we are
     * creating.
     * 
     * @return an array of {@link TrustManager} initialized with the default trust
     *         managers.
     */
    @SneakyThrows
    private TrustManager[] trustManagers() {
        TrustManagerFactory defaultTrustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory
                .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        // Using null here init the trustManagerFactory with the default trust store.
        defaultTrustManagerFactory.init((KeyStore) null);

        // only need the default trust managers if the CA for mongo is already in the
        // default trust store for the JVM (e.g. via bosh managed trust store or via the
        return defaultTrustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
    }

    /**
     * Creates an array of {@link KeyManager} containing the certificate and
     * privateKey provided in a in memory only {@link KeyStore} with alias
     * {@link #MONGO_KEY_ENTRY_ALIAS} used for x509 authentication. This is a dymaic
     * key manager containing the private key and certificate in the store for use
     * by the {@link SSLContext} that this class creates.
     * 
     * @param certificate
     * @param privateKey
     * @return an array of {@link KeyManager} initialized with the in memory
     *         {@link KeyStore}.
     */
    @SneakyThrows
    private KeyManager[] keyManagers(X509Certificate certificate, PrivateKey privateKey) {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keyStore.load(null); // You don't need the KeyStore instance to come from a file.
        keyStore.setKeyEntry(MONGO_KEY_ENTRY_ALIAS, privateKey, "".toCharArray(), new Certificate[] { certificate });

        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "".toCharArray());
        return keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();
    }

    /**
     * Parses the PEM Encoded <b> mongo.x509.private-key </b> property to a
     * {@link PrivateKey}.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @SneakyThrows
    private PrivateKey privateKey() {
        try (PEMParser parser = new PEMParser(new StringReader(properties.getPrivateKey()))) {
            return PEM_KEY_CONVERTER.getPrivateKey(PrivateKeyInfo.class.cast(parser.readObject()));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Parses the PEM Encoded <b>mongo.x509.certificate</b> property to
     * {@link X509Certificate}.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @SneakyThrows
    private X509Certificate x509Certificate() {
        try (PEMParser parser = new PEMParser(new StringReader(properties.getCertificate()))) {
            return X509_CERTIFICATE_CONVERTER.getCertificate(X509CertificateHolder.class.cast(parser.readObject()));
        }
    }

}
```

Hence the certificate and key was injected through MongoX509Properties which loaded the properties from a credhub.
Another key to this was how you parse the certificate. For that we used the dependency:

```xml
<!-- Bouncy Castle for parsing PEM encoded private key and certificate -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.65</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

All  options required for x.509 authentication should be specifiable in the connection string in recent drivers. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63188502/how-can-i-connect-with-x509-by-putting-all-options-in-the-connection-string-in-n/63194197#63194197) for examples in various languages.

1. Study [connection string documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/).
2. Construct a connection string containing all of the options.
3. Use this connection string to connect to your deployment using `mongo` shell. Do not pass any options using command-line arguments, use connection string only.
4. Use the same connection string with your driver.

To troubleshoot authentication errors, read the [server log](https://github.com/p-mongo/mongodb-faq#server-log).

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#urioption.tlsCertificateKeyFile, It says it is not supported by few drivers, I am guessing Java is one them and that is why it expects JVM Arguments