# Failed to connect MongoDB by native db driver

Tags: mongodb, go

I am trying to connect MongoDB by the native MongoDB driver with go language
([ref](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver)).

Here is my snapcode.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

const (
    account               = "rootAdmin"
    password              = "12345678"
    iP                    = "127.0.0.1"
    port                  = 27017
    tlsCertificateKeyFile = "D:/cert/wa.pem"
)

type mongoStuff struct {
    ctx    context.Context
    client *mongo.Client
    cancel context.CancelFunc
}

func connectToMongoDB() *mongoStuff {
    uri := fmt.Sprintf("mongodb://%v:%v@%v:%v/?authSource=admin&tlsCertificateKeyFile=%v&tls=true",
        account,
        password,
        iP,
        port,
        tlsCertificateKeyFile)
    credential := options.Credential{
        AuthMechanism: "MONGODB-X509",
        Username:      account,
        Password:      password,
    }
    log.Println(uri)
    clientOpts := options.Client().ApplyURI(uri).SetAuth(credential)
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOpts)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Dead connect")
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return &mongoStuff{ctx, client, cancel}
}

func disconnectMongoDB(mongodb *mongoStuff) {
    cancel := mongodb.cancel
    client := mongodb.client
    ctx := mongodb.ctx
    defer cancel()
    defer func() {
        if err := client.Disconnect(ctx); err != nil {
            log.Println("Dead disconnect")
            panic(err)
        }
    }()
}

func insertExamples(mongodb *mongoStuff) {
    ctx := mongodb.ctx
    var db *mongo.Database = mongodb.client.Database("documentation_examples")
    coll := db.Collection("inventory_insert")
    err := coll.Drop(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Dead drop")
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    {
        result, err := coll.InsertOne(
            ctx,
            bson.D{
                {"item", "canvas"},
                {"qty", 100},
                {"tags", bson.A{"cotton"}},
                {
                    "size", bson.D{
                        {"h", 28},
                        {"w", 35.5},
                        {"uom", "cm"},
                    }},
            })
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Dead insertone")
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        log.Printf("insertone success. id=%v", result.InsertedID)
    }
}

func main() {
    mongodb := connectToMongoDB()
    defer disconnectMongoDB(mongodb)
    insertExamples(mongodb)
}
```

Whenever I run the code, it just comes up with the below error.

> connection() error occured during connection handshake: auth error: round trip error: (AuthenticationFailed) **No user name provided**

I can't figure out what's going on.

Comment: Authentication mechanism mentioning X.509 looks strange to me: this standard defines the format of public key certificates (those used in TLS and elsewhere).

Comment: Yes, I'd like to connect to Mongo with TLS. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Did you configure MongoDB properly to use cert and user:pass?

Comment: It seems to run good. I can connect to server by MongoDB Compass with certification file(*.pem file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To authenticate with x.509, the username should be either the common name of the certificate or empty. You seem to be attempting some mix of password and x.509 authentication.

All required options can be provided in the URI. See [How can I connect with X509 by putting all options in the connection string in node.js driver for mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63188502/how-can-i-connect-with-x509-by-putting-all-options-in-the-connection-string-in-n/63194197#63194197).

If you insist on specifying credentials not in a URI, reference driver documentation that describes how to do that for x509 credentials.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. All required options can be provided in the URI.